# How to get the screen coordinate of web-page elements in BHO

Tags: internet-explorer-7, coordinates, bho, iwebbrowser2

I am writing a BHO object for IE.

I want the screen position of the top-left of the web-page. How can i get this position?
The topleft of the first element in DOM returns (0,0). The webBrowser.Left or Top returns the position of the browser but not the top-left of the page. I am using IWebBrowser2.

Thanks a million,

-anony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.

The IHTMLElement2.getBoundingClientRect() and IHTMLElement2.getClientRects() solved the problem.

-Datte

Answer (score 1):

You may have already figured this out, but using [ClientToScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931003.aspx) function might help you.