# IE plugin API (interfaces)

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, activex

I'm  working with a ActiveX plugin architecture. It works fine. But now I need to get access to the window in "Document" for drawing my own video stream into.

```
<object id="MyPlugin" name="MyPlugin" type="application/myplugin" classid="CLSID:1BAEC849-6C36-4DEE-905F-111111111" width="200" height="200"></object>
```

I implement next interfaces:

```
class MyActiveXObject : public IObjectSafety,
                              public IProvideClassInfo2,
                              public IConnectionPointContainer,
                              public IObjectWithSite,
                              public IOleInPlaceObject,
                              public IPreviewHandler
```

Question : What intefaces I need to implement (or call) to get right position for output window in browser?
How i can get HWND for this window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the screen coordinate of web-page elements in BHO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330278/how-to-get-the-screen-coordinate-of-web-page-elements-in-bho)